# AngularJS ngRepeat orderBy not working with DateTime string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please see this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/luke88jones/MfLqa/2/

```
<div ng-repeat="booking in testBookings | orderBy: 'booking.sortDate'">
      <span>{{booking.bookingDateTime | date:'dd-MMM-yy HH:mm'}}</span>      
</div>
```

I am trying to use the orderBy to sort a ng-repeat. Our data currently uses the bookingDateTime for the filter which isn't working. I wasn't sure if angular wasn't resolving the function so have put in the sortDate property as an ISO string and tried to sort using this but still it doesn't seem to be working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<div ng-repeat="booking in testBookings | orderBy:'sortDate'">
```

working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Bq7hb/

Comment: It doesn't order correctly if the dates are from different time zones