# AngularJS - Can't sorted DateTime with ngRepeat orderBy

Tags: angularjs, datetime, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters, angularjs-orderby

After reading a tons of post on SO ([post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22503875/angularjs-ngrepeat-orderby-not-working-with-datetime-string), [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261348/descending-order-by-date-filter-in-angularjs), [post3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652354/angular-orderby-with-date-string) ...) and googling, I can't still figure out how to sort the datetimes inside my ng-repeat.

Here is what I've done :

The ng-repeat inside my index.html :

```
<div ng-repeat="oneItem in groupesItems.ITEMS | orderBy:'-myDate'" class="item">
                                        ...
 <div class="course-date">{[{oneItem.myDate | date:'dd MMMM yyyy hh : mm'}]}</div>
                                        ...
</div>
```

I've also read that I've to convert myDate to Date object, because Angular considers it as a string. So in my angular controller, this is what I've done :

```
($scope.groupesItems.ITEMS).forEach(function(data){
        data.myDate = new Date(data.myDate);
    });
```

But nothing is working !

Please Help ! what I've overlooking ?

Comment: First check; have you seen what data you are getting in console and if that contains myDate?

Comment: what $scope.groupesItems contains?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use some `temp` variable via `getTime` method:

```
<div ng-repeat="oneItem in groupesItems.ITEMS | orderBy:'-temp'" class="item">
    <div class="course-date">{[{oneItem.myDate | date:'dd MMMM yyyy hh : mm'}]}</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
($scope.groupesItems.ITEMS).forEach(function(data){
     data.temp = new Date(data.myDate).getTime();
});
```

Also you can try `reverse`(`true` after `orderBy:'myDate':`) without changing javascript part:

```
<div ng-repeat="oneItem in groupesItems.ITEMS | orderBy:'myDate':true" class="item">
    <div class="course-date">{[{oneItem.myDate | date:'dd MMMM yyyy hh : mm'}]}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx, it worked great :). But what did I miss on my code?

Comment: At your case `reverse` is answer. Check out updated answer.